# How to reduce code duplication when signing in via multiple OAuth2 providers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am using **Node.js**, **Express**, **Passport**, **Mongoose** node modules.

There are two cases when user clicks `sign in with provider`. Here is an example of a GitHub Strategy:

*1. If user is already logged in, link this github account to the currently logged in user.*

*2. If user is not logged in, then check if it's the first time signing in with Github or is it a returning user.*

### Q: Can I consolidate this code somehow using MongoDB query builder or some other technique?

```
if (req.user) {
   // Already logged in. Clicked on "Link Github account" on Settings page.
    User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
      // Merge Github with local account for the current user.
      user.github = profile.id;
      user.tokens.push({ kind: 'github', accessToken: accessToken });
      user.profile.name = profile.displayName;
      user.profile.email = user.profile.email || profile._json.email;
      user.profile.picture = user.profile.picture || profile._json.avatar_url;
      user.profile.location = user.profile.location || profile._json.location;
      user.profile.website = user.profile.website || profile._json.blog;
      user.save(function(err) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });
  } else {
    // Unauthenticated user arriving from Login/Signup page.
    User.findOne({ github: profile.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
      // Returning user. Stop here.
      if (existingUser) return done(null, existingUser);
      // First time. Create a new user.
      var user = new User();
      user.github = profile.id;
      user.tokens.push({ kind: 'github', accessToken: accessToken });
      user.profile.name = profile.displayName;
      user.profile.email = profile._json.email;
      user.profile.picture = profile._json.avatar_url;
      user.profile.location = profile._json.location;
      user.profile.website = profile._json.blog;
      user.save(function(err) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you asking, but here, you can just take the similar parts into a function like this:

```
if (req.user) {
  // Already logged in. Clicked on "Link Github account" on Settings page.
  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
    // Merge Github with local account for the current user.
    updateUserGithub(user, profile, done);
  });
} else {
  // Unauthenticated user arriving from Login/Signup page.
  User.findOne({ github: profile.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
    // Returning user. Stop here.
    if (existingUser) return done(null, existingUser);
    // First time. Create a new user.
    var user = new User();
    updateUserGithub(user, profile, done);
  });
}

function updateUserGithub(user, profile, done) {
    user.github = profile.id;
    user.tokens.push({ kind: 'github', accessToken: accessToken });
    user.profile.name = profile.displayName;
    user.profile.email = user.profile.email || profile._json.email;
    user.profile.picture = user.profile.picture || profile._json.avatar_url;
    user.profile.location = user.profile.location || profile._json.location;
    user.profile.website = user.profile.website || profile._json.blog;
    user.save(function(err) {
      done(err, user);
    });   
}
```

If you didn't have the default values logic in here(like `user.profile.website || profile._json.blog;`) you could have used mongodb update command instead of getting and saving the whole document.